# React search filter form

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I have been trying to set a search filter form. I am getting data from API (an array of cake objects with "id", "cake_name", "category" etc properties), these get displayed properly. But somehow my search function is not working? It should allow the user to input a name of a cake which then would be filtered through the cakes available and only the searched one(s) would be displayed.

I am getting this error:
[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nGWe1.png)

Here is my code:
context.js:

```js
import React, { useState, useContext, useEffect } from "react";
import { useCallback } from "react";

const url = "https://cakeaddicts-api.herokuapp.com/cakes";

const AppContext = React.createContext();

const AppProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
  const [searchTerm, setSearchTerm] = useState("");
  const [cakes, setCakes] = useState([]);
  const [filteredData, setFilteredData] = useState([]);

  const fetchCakes = async () => {
    setLoading(true);
    try {
      const response = await fetch(url);
      const cakes = await response.json();
      if (cakes) {
        const newCakes = cakes.map((cake) => {
          const {
            id,
            image,
            cake_name,
            category,
            type,
            ingredients,
            instructions,
          } = cake;
          return {
            id,
            image,
            cake_name,
            category,
            type,
            ingredients,
            instructions,
          };
        });
        setCakes(newCakes);
        console.log(newCakes);
      } else {
        setCakes([]);
      }
      setLoading(false);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
      setLoading(false);
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchCakes();
  }, []);

  return (
    <AppContext.Provider
      value={{
        loading,
        cakes,
        setSearchTerm,
        searchTerm,
        filteredData,
        setFilteredData,
      }}
    >
      {children}
    </AppContext.Provider>
  );
};
// make sure use
export const useGlobalContext = () => {
  return useContext(AppContext);
};

export { AppContext, AppProvider };
```

SearchForm.js

```js
import React from "react";
import { useGlobalContext } from "../context";
import CakeList from "./CakeList";

const SearchForm = () => {
  const { cakes, setSearchTerm, searchTerm, setFilteredData } =
    useGlobalContext;

  const searchCakes = () => {
    if (searchTerm !== "") {
      const filteredData = cakes.filter((item) => {
        return Object.values(item)
          .join("")
          .toLowerCase()
          .includes(searchTerm.toLowerCase());
      });
      setFilteredData(filteredData);
    } else {
      setFilteredData(cakes);
    }
  };

  return (
    <section className="section search">
      <form className="search-form">
        <div className="form-control">
          <label htmlFor="name">Search Your Favourite Cake</label>
          <input
            type="text"
            id="name"
            onChange={(e) => searchCakes(e.target.value)}
          />
        </div>
      </form>
    </section>
  );
};

export default SearchForm;
```

CakeList.js:

```js
import React from "react";
import Cake from "./Cake";
import Loading from "./Loading";
import { useGlobalContext } from "../context.js";

const CakeList = () => {
  const { cakes, loading, searchTerm, filteredResults } = useGlobalContext();

  if (loading) {
    return <Loading />;
  }

  return (
    <section className="section">
      <h2 className="section-title">Cakes</h2>
      <div className="cakes-center">
        {searchTerm.length > 1
          ? filteredResults.map((cake) => {
              return <Cake key={cake.id} {...cake} />;
            })
          : cakes.map((item) => {
              return <Cake key={item.id} {...item} />;
            })}
      </div>
    </section>
  );
};

export default CakeList;
```

App.js:

```js
import React from "react";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Routes } from "react-router-dom";
// import pages
import Home from "./pages/Home";
import About from "./pages/About";
import SingleCake from "./pages/SingleCake";
import Error from "./pages/Error";
// import components
import Navbar from "./components/Navbar";
function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <Navbar />
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
        <Route path="/about" element={<About />} />
        <Route path="/cake/:id" element={<SingleCake />} />
        <Route path="*" element={<Error />} />
      </Routes>
    </Router>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Can someone please help me with this search form? I have tried so many things and nothing is working :( Anyone?

Comment: useGlobalContext  is a function

Comment: Btw, filteredData is derived state. From your Provider return value you can instead write `filteredData: searchTerm ? cakes.filter(your filter code) : cakes`. Then you can remove the filteredData state and all the code for setFilteredData in SearchForm.

Answer (score 0):

On line 11 of SearchForm.js, there is a part that reads `cakes.filter(`. To resolve the typeError, change this to `cakes?.filter(`. This will only execute the filter if cakes is defined. It's a feature in javascript called Optional Chaining, introduced in ES2020.

Learn about it more [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining)